# Byline for Google Authorship in a foreign language

Tags: google-authorship

I setup Google Authorship for my blog today. When testing it on the structured data testing tool, Everything is great, except the "Automatically detected author name on webpage", which was expected, because I don't have a "by Άγγελος Κυρίτσης" line.

The reason is that the blog and the posts are in Greek, as is my name, and it would be stupid to have a "Written by" in English just for Google.

Is there a way for Google to recognize the established authorship in Greek (or any other language, for that matter)?

Answer (score 2):

Google should recognize your name in most languages, I have seen examples in Hebrew and other languages.

Did you connect your blog to your Google plus personal page? It should take the author name from your Google plus page, no matter what languages it is written in.

Comment: Yes, everything else checks out at the structured data testing tool and the Authorship Email Verification. The email address has been verified, it can find the public contributor-to link from google+ profile to my blog. The only thing missing is the "Automatically detected author name on webpage", even though I made sure I have the rel=author atribute at my name and it is spelled exactly as in my G+ profile.